# unable to remove certificate from system key-chain

Tags: macos, security, keychain

I am not able to remove a certificate from system key chain on macos.

I am able to do it in "login" key-chain, but in "system" key-chain the "Delete" menu voice is disabled.

What I tried is:

```
sudo security dump-keychain /Library/Keychain/System.keychain
```

I get the list of elements in the keychain, but when I try to do:

```
sudo security delete-certificate -c "Apple Development: myname (L...)" /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

I got this error:

```
Unable to delete certificate matching "Apple Development: myname (L...)"
```

But the name of the certify is that. Maybe the brackets in the certificate name?